# How to Re-Render a Header functional component on a function called by onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, rerender

**Some context:** I'm using REACT on my web app and im settin up the logout process. When I click on Logout button, it cleans the local storage and logs out.

**Issue:** When this happens, the HEADER component keeps showing the "session links" instead of the "guest links". I understand that RE-Rendering the Header component which actually uses a Ternary based on Login STATUS to decide which links to show. Looking for how to do this, i found that when you update a state from the functional component it will cause to re-render, but i'm not sure how to implement it.

Hope this brings enough context, here the code:

```
function Header({authReducer}) {
    const history = useHistory();
     
    const handleLogout = () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("persist:auth");
      
      history.push("/home");
     
    }


    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        '@global': {
            ul: {
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
            listStyle: 'none',
            },
        },
        appBar: {
            borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
        },
        toolbar: {
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
        },
        toolbarTitle: {
            flexGrow: 1,
        },
        link: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1, 1.5),
        },
        heroContent: {
            padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 6),
        }
    }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  const guestLinks = (
      <>
          <nav>
            <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="/" className={classes.link}>
              Inicio
            </Link>
            <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="/plans" className={classes.link}>
              Planes
            </Link>
            <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="/contact" className={classes.link}>
              Contacto
            </Link>
          </nav>
          <Button href="login" color="primary" variant="outlined" className={classes.link}>
            Iniciar Sesión
          </Button>
      </>
  )

  const sessionLinks = (
      <>
          <nav>
            <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="/binnacle" className={classes.link}>
              Bitácora
            </Link>
            <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="/information" className={classes.link}>
              Información de la obra
            </Link>
            <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="/financial" className={classes.link}>
              Información Financiera
            </Link>
            <Link variant="button" color="textPrimary" href="/support" className={classes.link}>
              Soporte
            </Link>
          </nav>
          <Button color="primary" variant="outlined" className={classes.link} onClick={handleLogout} >
            Salir
          </Button>
      </>
  )

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="stick   y" color="default" elevation={0} className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <Typography align="left" variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.toolbarTitle}>
            Bitácora Online
          </Typography>
         {authReducer.isLoggedIn ? sessionLinks : guestLinks}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </React.Fragment>
    
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    authReducer: state.authReducer
  })

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

Comment: For some more information, see [this issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/585).

Answer (score 1):

You should be to use an useState() hook for conditional sessionlinks and gestlinks, because when it change you could  make render...

And check if you route /home it's a redirect to /

Example like I feel:

```
const [checkLog,setCheckLog] = useState(false)
const HandleLogout =()=>{
 localStorage.... 
 setCheckLog(true)
}

//into return 

......
checkLog ? <GuestLinks /> : 
<SessionLinks />
```

No se si me entendió a lo que me refiero con usar states y un pequeño checker para que reaccione al handled